# How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in InstallSchema.php?

Tags: magento2, module, sql, install-script, orm

In the `InstallSchema.php`, I would like to add an unique contraint on a combination of column.

In SQL, it would be done with this request:

```
ALTER TABLE `linked_cities` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`vendor`, `zip`, `city`);
```

Is there a way to do that with the Magento ORM in order to avoid any further intervention on the database?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved: in the script, I directly executed the request:

```
$myRequest = "ALTER TABLE...";
$installer->getConnection()->query($myRequest );
```

EDIT: finally found how to do it with the Magento methods:

```
$myTable->addIndex(
            $installer->getIdxName($tableName, $arrayOfColumnsName),
            arrayOfColumnsName,
            ['type' => 'unique']
        );
```